# How to convert string of type YY/MM/DD to java.util.Date?

Tags: java, date, format

I have searched  but did not find the exact format(YY/MM/DD) for parsing the String.

How can I convert a string of type YY/MM/DD to `java.util.Date`. I have strings in the format "160310", "160211".

Comment: show what you are tried so far

Comment: Is it always same format of string date?

Comment: So you are assuming "160310" is not the 16th March 2010

Answer (score 9):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` for this.

```
String target = "160211";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date result =  df.parse(target);
```

For more options and info you can always checkout the full documentation about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @ScaryWombat although in Java 8 it might be time to use the JSR 310 DateTime library ;)

Answer (score 1):

Nit: The format isn't "YY/MM/DD", it's "YYMMDD" (note the slashes). Regardless, you can use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse such strings:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
Date date = df.parse("160211");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code , It will

```
    String mydate="160310";
    SimpleDateFormat sd=new SimpleDateFormat("YYmmdd",Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = sd.parse(mydate);
    System.out.println(date);`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have reached the area of Java 8, you might also consider

```
        Date dt = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.from(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMdd").parse("160123")));
```

But in fact, you would not do the conversion to the old ugly date if you can avoid it, but rather go along with the LocalDate you created on your way.

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");

        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = sdf.parse("160310");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```